# How can I try Amazon Web Services without pay something

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I want to try deploying a simple database application to AWS RDS.
Do you have some idea how I can to try it ?
Is it really free to try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is what you are looking for: http://aws.amazon.com/free/
More details about the limitations: http://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/

But you need a valid credit card...

Comment: Do you have some practical experience with it ? With deploying database application.